# Wrote an Invisible whitespace in VScode, but showed in command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, whitespace, rust-rustlings

I was playing with [rustlings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings) untile I've reached the exercise [primitive_types2.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/04_primitive_types/primitive_types2.rs).

To print in output [`Neither alphabetic nor numeric!`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/9691c3cb55484ce9676c85ad4673b38e06100303/exercises/04_primitive_types/primitive_types3.rs#L17) I've started to mess up with `ALT + NUMPAD` and I've generated this line.

`let your_character = '­☻';`

If you copy-paste it, you will notice that there is **an invisible whitespace** before the smile (try to delete or move the cursor with arrows).

```rust
Compiling of exercises/04_primitive_types/primitive_types2.rs failed! Please try again. Here's the output:
error: character literal may only contain one codepoint
  --> exercises/04_primitive_types/primitive_types2.rs:22:26
   |
22 |     let your_character = '­☻';// Finish this line like the example! What's your favorite character?
   |                          ^^^^
   |
help: if you meant to write a `str` literal, use double quotes
   |
22 |     let your_character = "­☻";// Finish this line like the example! What's your favorite character?
   |                          ~~~~

error: aborting due to 1 previous error
```

This white space is printed in Output.
[image]

Looking around, I've found some information about it, but if I paste them in VSCode, they're highlighted by a yellow rectangle.
[image] [image]

Is there a way to figure out how I generated it?

How can I avoid, find, and fix this problem if it happens in a real-world scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to figure out how I generated it?

I copy-pasted into an online text-to-hex converter and identified that what you have there is [U+00AD 'SOFT HYPHEN'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen).  To generate it, by default:

- on Windows: hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>, type <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, then release <kbd>ALT</kbd>; or
- on Linux: hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, type
  <kbd>U</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, then release <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
  and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

(I don't believe, by default, there is any keyboard shortcut on macOS that will produce this character).

> How can I avoid, find, and fix this problem if it happens in a real-world scenario?

I'd recommend the [Gremlins tracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins) extension.